# dynamically create Databindings in a MAUI Grid

Tags: c#, maui

I want to create a table dynamically. The label objects should receive a binding as text property. Since I don't have a label instance I don't know how to assign the binding with SetBinding. Someone has an idea?

Code:

```
...

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                if(j == 0){
                    grid.Add(new BoxView{
                        Color = Colors.OrangeRed
                    }, i, 0);
                    grid.Add(new Label{
                    
                        Text = headerText[i],
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                    }, i, 0);
                } else{
                    if(j % 2 == 0){
                        grid.Add(new BoxView{
                            Color = Colors.WhiteSmoke
                        }, i, j);
                        grid.Add(new Label{
                            Text = j.ToString() + " : " + i.ToString(),
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                        }, i, j);
                    } else{
                        grid.Add(new BoxView{
                            Color = Colors.LightGray
                        }, i, j);
                        grid.Add(new Label {
                            Text = j.ToString() + " : " + i.ToString(),
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                        }, i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        vsl.Add(img);
        vsl.Add(grid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how groups work in a collection view? You can get some pretty neat ideas from there. Instead of this.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this

```
grid.Add(new Label{
                
                    Text = headerText[i],
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                }, i, 0);
```

do this

```
var label = new Label { ... };
label.SetBinding(...);
grid.Add(label, i, 0);
```

or this

```
// you only need to declare this once, 
// but you can reuse it
Label label;

grid.Add(label = (new Label{...}));
label.SetBinding(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "YourValue");` to achieve this.

You can add new variable `MyValue` to get the special value of array(e.g.`Words`) and you can bind the `MyValue` to a Label.

```
   // add a variable to identify the index of array
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Words { get; set; } = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three","Four","Five","Six" };

    public string MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Words[Key];
        }
        set { }
    }
```

And use it as follows:

```
                       var label = new Label
                    {
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                    };

                    Key = i;
                    MyValue = Words[i];
                   
                    // set bind for this label
                    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "MyValue");
                    label.BindingContext = this;
```

Based on your code,I created a demo to achieve this.
You can refer to the following code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
   // add a variable to identify the index of array
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<string> Words { get; set; } = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three","Four","Five","Six" };

    public string MyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Words[Key];
        }
        set { }
    }

    public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    grid.Add(new BoxView
                    {
                        Color = Colors.OrangeRed
                    }, i, 0);


                    var label = new Label
                    {
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                    };

                    Key = i;
                    MyValue = Words[i];
                   
                    // set bind for this label
                    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "MyValue");
                    label.BindingContext = this;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---> print txt is: "+label.Text);
                    grid.Add(label, i, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (j % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        grid.Add(new BoxView
                        {
                            Color = Colors.WhiteSmoke
                        }, i, j);
                        grid.Add(new Label
                        {
                            Text = j.ToString() + " : " + i.ToString(),
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                        }, i, j);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid.Add(new BoxView
                        {
                            Color = Colors.LightGray
                        }, i, j);
                        grid.Add(new Label
                        {
                            Text = j.ToString() + " : " + i.ToString(),
                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                        }, i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a little bit. But i don't need the binding for the header cells. I need t to populate the rest of the table. And thats my problem. 
I have an answer from a websocket with values as json. 
My thought was to fill a list of a class with just these 6 properties. And every time values in the list change, the whole thing should also change in the table. I can then specify this list as a binding and update it accordingly. But I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: `But i don't need the binding for the header cells`   Could you please elaborate on your problem?

Comment: The whole src file : https://codeshare.io/VZ7nPO

Comment: Yes, you can. You can first get the Json as a model, then populate the data to your table. But from the code you posted , I couldn't find the Jason data.

Comment: I have to pause this, because my websocket doesn deliver behind the maui application from which i get the json string...

Comment: You can try to share the Json string sample , then we can provide you the corresponding solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that fits better for me. Instead using a grid i used a ListView with an ObservableCollection.